# Build Qt 5.2 for windows ce 6

Tags: qt, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, qt5

I tried to build qt 5.2.1 (opensource.zip) on a Windows 7 64 bit machine with Visual Studio 2005 Professional while having ActivePerl etc. installed. I used the Visual Studio 2005 Command prompt with the following line for configure:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2005 -xplatform wince60standard-armv4i-msvc2005 -opensource -nomake examples
```

which ends up in the following output after about 2 min.:

```
…
qglobal.cpp
qmalloc.cpp
qlibraryinfo.cpp
qnumeric.cpp
qlogging.cpp
D:\qt-source5.2.1\qtbase\src\corelib\global\qlogging.cpp(96) : error C3861:             “GetConsoleWindow”: identifier not found.
Code will be generated…
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ““C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     8\VC\BIN\cl.EXE”“: return code “0×2”
Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2
```

I also tried to do just a simple:,

```
configure
```

within Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt -> Ends up in the same error. 
Does anybody know what wents wrong here? Am i doing something totally wrong or missing something?
I also posted this to the qt Forums of a thread created by a user who had a similar problem -> http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36177/
But nobody replied there.

EDIT: Today i updated my question in QT forums. See -> http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36177/  I modified the problem file qtbase\src\corelib\global\qlogging.h and added the following on top of it:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT 
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0×0500 
#endif
```

I found this solution while searching for “getConsoleWindow” problems. The reference is written down as remark here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx 
After this my configure runs fine without any problems. But now I expected the following error after calling nmake. After nmake runs ~30 mins i got this output:

```
d:\readonly\qtsrc\qtbase\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h(666) : error 
C2244: 'QVector<T>::erase' : unable to match function definition to an existing   declaration definition 'QVector<T>::iterator     QVector<T>::erase(QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator,QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator)'
existing declarations
'QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator QVector<T>::erase(QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator)'
'QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator QVector<T>::erase(QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator,QTypedArrayData<T>::iterator)'
```

There are some more errors but all with QVector::insert and QVector::erase. I Googled a bit and found this post here which looks like a similar problem and is also not replied yet: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36735
I think i have to say that i compile for custom ce sdk. So i changed the qtbase\mkspecs\wince60standard-armv4i-msvc2005\qmake.conf and added additional includes and libraries there. I also use the following defines there:

```
DEFINES += WINCE WINDOWS WINDOWS_CE_OS _WIN32_WCE=0×600 UNDER_CE=0×600 ARM _ARM ARMV4I  UNICODE UNICODE _USE_32BIT_TIME_T _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE $$CE_ARCH _AMRV7 armv7 ARM QT_NO_CLIPBOARD QT_NO_ACCESSIBILITY QT_NO_NATIVE_GESTURES QT_NOSTANDARDSHELL_UI_MODEL
```

Is it so hard to compile qt 5.2.1 for ce? Should i use an older version of qt (i need at least qt5 for JSON handling)? Any suggestions regarding this issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Use thirdpaty library for JSON. Visual Studio 2005 is too old compiler. For example - jsoncpp or QJson.